# Haskell Data Structure

Tags: haskell, recursion, memoization

I am trying to build a data-structure in Haskell which functions can use to avoid re-computing values. For example, say I had the function:

```
f :: Int -> Int -> Int
f 1 1 == 1
f m n
    | abs m > n = 0
    | OTHERWISE if value of f m n has already been computed by another recursive branch, return that value and add it to the "database"
    | OTHERWISE return f (m-1) (n-1) + f (m - 1) n
```

I have already looked at memoization, but haven't been able to implement a solution :\

Suggestions? :)

Answer (score 5):

A great explanation is [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Memoization).

I love [memoize](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/memoize-0.6) package :)

Example (solving the *"A frog is jumping up the staircase..."* problem):

```
import Data.Function.Memoize 

ladder :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer 
ladder n k = g n 
  where g = memoize f 
        f 0 = 1 
        f x = sum [g (x - y) | y <- [1..if x < k then x else k]]
```

Comment: Hi @josesuan, thanks, unfortunately this is my problem, I had come across similar examples, but struggling to understand how it actually works. (In particular, the last line)